# How do I use redstone repeaters to stretch the redstone limit?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-redstone

I was on my Survival world and was making piston doors. I since it's underground, I had to make it twist and turn. When I tried to add the repeater to stretch the redstone limit, when I flicked the lever, the pistons wouldn't move. I tried with less redstone and a shorter distance away from the pistons. It worked that time, but I need it longer. How do I make it stretch longer?

Comment: did u make sure u put the repeater facing the right way?

Comment: Close vote retracted; a closer reading (and the edit!) makes it clear what you're asking.

Answer (score 8):

Add more than one redstone repeater. A redstone signal will only stretch for 15 blocks before disappearing, so add multiple repeaters to extend the travelling distance of the signal to the pistons.

Comment: also, repeaters are have an input on one end, and an output on the other, so they don't work around corners

Answer (score 2):

Redstone signals have a strength between 1 and 15.  If you place a torch and redstone dust next to it, that dust is at 15.  Connect a second and that is strength 14.  When you get to one, you need a repeater.

You can place all of your redstone dust trails and power from one end.  Look at the dust, it indicates if it has a signal.  Place a repeater where ever signal stops.  Then continue down trail until the next one is needed.

[image: Signal Indication]

Also, if your signal is going vertically up or down, use a torch tower instead of stairs.  The signal amplifies itself so no repeaters are needed.

[image: Torch Towers]